# Android: Access mysql database, forbidden files

Tags: php, android

I'm trying to open a connection between my android emulator and server (currently testing on local.)

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database)

The problem arises when trying to read the php file itself.

I have internet permissions setup in the manifest file, so thats ok; what get's recorded into the JSON array however is infact a "403 Forbidden" html message, mentioning that I'm not allowed access to the file getAllPeopleBornAfter.php

If anyones encountered a solution to this problem I'd greatly appreciate some help with it. Otherwise, I was hoping someone could tell me how I could allow public use of php scripts without allowing the file for download / be seen?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you access the file via a normal desktop browser? A PHP file cannot be download when the server supports PHP. It will always get interpreted.

Comment: Hey mate, I learned that Android reads 'localhost' as it's own personal host, so you have to use you home IP 192.16... as a host. In a browser, if I type in 'localhost' as a root to access the file, I can access it; if I use my IP, it says forbidden. A rather annoying conundrum.

Comment: Then this is a web server or firewall issue. Check you web server configuration so that you website is accessible via IP and not only via local host.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Server Configuration.

Set Listen to :

```
Listen *:80
```

(Where 80 is the port you are listening at. Or any other port for that matter.)

And in the Alias Section of the configuration file:
Comment The 'Deny From All' Using '#'. In case you don't want everyone to access but only from particular addresses then insert the Ip Addresses using Allow as shown.

```
<Directory "i:/myproject">
Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order deny,allow
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from 192.168.1.15
#Deny from all
Require all granted
</Directory>
```